# How to open a file from server via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to open a file. I get an error that the address is wrong.

> 'Cannot connect to 192.000.0.00/system/employee.lst, Please check if the web address is correct'

```vb
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="ftp://192.000.0.00/system/employee.lst", Origin:=932 _
  , StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
  ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False _
  , Space:=False, Other:=False, _
  TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

When I try to open this address `ftp://192.000.0.00/system/` with folder explorer there is no problem.

Comment: If the above is a literal copy of your code, then you have a basic syntax error: Remove the line-break (or add an underscore) after `Other:=False,`. (i.e. you need to join to `TrailingMinusNumbers:=True`)

Comment: Please update your question to provide details of the error (error code, description, etc)

Comment: @SuperSymmetry the error I am getting is 'Cannot connect to ftp://192.000.0.00/system/employee.lst , Please check if the web address is correct' so there is no number or something...

Comment: It could be a forward/back slash mismatch? you could try replacing the forward slashes with backwards slashes and see if that helps?

Comment: @Tragamor unfortunately, it does not help.... Could it be a network problem?